# My ASP.NET site doesn't find files located in different folders

Tags: asp.net

My website has many pages which operate on some data  in a database. Since many procedures are the same, I have put all of these "general" functions inside a (public partial) static class and saved it in the App_Code folder as suggested by Visual Studio:

```
Root
 |
 +-- App_Code
 |       |
 |       +-- GeneralStuff.cs
 |       |
 |       +-- DataStructure.cs
 |
 +-- Default.aspx
 |
 +-- Default.aspx.cs
 |
 +-- etc
```

The problem is that whenever I try to use something defined inside my GeneralStuff class the page doesn't compile because it can't find that class:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'GeneralStuff' does not exist in the current context
```

I can't also use the files that are saved in the App_Data folder. Note that everything works fine when running from Visual Studio.

**Additional details:** Here's the version I'm using:
 - Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3625;
 - ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3634;

Any hints?

Cheers

Comment: Can you post the compile error?

Comment: Your solution compile in VS? Do you deploy your App_Code on the web server?

Comment: @Jeff: Here it is, check my edit

Comment: @Angelodev: Yes, the solution compiles fine in VS and the folder is in the same folder as all the other pages and the web.config file (but not in the root of the server).

Comment: Post your GeneralStuff.cs class

Comment: @Angelodev: it's about 500 lines of code

Answer (score 2):

Is your class declaration decorated by a namespace?  If so, you will need to include a reference to that namespace anywhere you want to use it (use the `using Namespace.Sub` syntax)

Comment: No, the GeneralStuff class isn't inside any namespace

Comment: What is the line of code that the compiler is bombing out on?

Comment: Every line which uses something defined in a code file placed in App_Code folder.

Comment: Yes: "d:\inetpub\webs\circololabaseit\progetto\Aggiornamento.aspx.cs(44,62): error CS0103: The name 'Gestore' does not exist in the current context" and also this one: "d:\inetpub\webs\circololabaseit\progetto\AggiungiForestale.aspx.cs(22,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NumeroTelefono' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  Do you have a line of code that you can share that is causing the compiler error(s) you mention?

Comment: Sorry, here it is: "lblID.Text = Gestore.NumeroForestali().ToString();"

Comment: Is `NumeroForestali()` a static function within the `Gestore` class?

Comment: Yes, everyting in that class is static as well as the class itself

Comment: Well I don't know how much more anyone will be able to help without seeing a lot more code :)